# How to save thumbnail from inputstream in java

Tags: java

I am sending inputstream from android app to my java webservice and i save in on my webserver using code:

```
            String filePath = dirPath + File.separator + imageName;         
        // save the file to the server
        try {
            File newFile = new File(filePath);
            boolean fileCreated = true;
            if (!newFile.exists()) {
                fileCreated = newFile.createNewFile();
            }
            if (fileCreated) {
                FileOutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                while ((read = file.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                outpuStream.flush();
                outpuStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                
        }
```

but now i want to save a 100*100 thumbnail image , can someone tell me how do i achieve this . I tried using this and it was giving me null exception without any error

```
ImageIO.read().getScaledInstance(100, 100, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

if someone can either tell me solution for not getting a null exception or tell me some other way and don't suggest any library please. Thanks, i'll really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You do these in sequence:

```
BufferedImage bim=null;
try {
     bim=ImageIO.read(newFile));
}
catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }

File outFile of=new File(..../myimage.png");

BufferedImage img=(BufferedImage)bim.getScaledInstance(100, 100, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);

try {
  ImageIO.write(img, "png", of);
} catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

--

You can scale the image like this:

```
  BufferedImage img=new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);        
  Graphics g=img.getGraphics();
  g.drawImage(bim, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null);
```

so replace that getScaledInstance with this.

Comment: well i tried it and it gives me the exception 
sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage

Comment: It returns null after reading
ImageIO.read(myinputstream);

and i have to put input stream in it because that's what i m getting

Comment: you have to show how you read the input stream - i dont see it in the above code

Comment: you said you save it in a file - so then read that file - and create the thumbnail